# PHP - calling function from another file without including it

Tags: php, function

I want to be able to call function from anywhere. So i could just write something like this: file.php:foo();. Is it possible?

Comment: If it isn't included somehow in the code you are executing, how on earth do you expect to be able to use it?

Comment: @Fluffeh: by magical pixie dust

Comment: No, sorry. Nice idea, though.

Comment: I mean something like including functions from that file to php build-in functions or anything like that. Just that I can call that function from anywhere.

Comment: @user2665393: anything particularly wrong with `include`?

Comment: You can declare this function as static method and use [spl_autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php) to load class in runtime

Comment: just don't want to include it everywhere

Comment: @user2665393: looking at your guessed syntax `file.php:foo();` - isn't `file.php` part in the beginning an include?

Comment: @user2665393 If you don't want to include your function everywhere then don;t use a global include file.  If you function generally needs to be available everywhere, use a global include file.

Comment: What would happen if there were two files with a declaration for the same function name?

Comment: @toscho A PHP fatal error, saying you can't redeclare.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be a solution for you, but it might.  You could wrap your functions into namespacing classes.

You could add a class called `file` with `foo` as a static function. So instead of calling `foo()`, you'd call `file::foo()`. You would then __autoload those namespaced classes.  To do that, you would have to somewhere define your autoload function, something like:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}
```

And then your file.php would look like:

```
class file {
   public static function foo() {
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should include the file where the function you want to use is defined:

```
include file.php;
```

Then you can normally call your function:

```
foo();
```

Note: You could also use `require`, `require_once` or `include_once`

If you're using classes, you could try [autoloading them](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: Yes is it really that much harder to write `include file.php; foo()` than your proposed `file.php:foo()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a function in another file without including it.

If it's a question of not wanting to include a bunch of files, you can consolidate your functions into one file (ie. functions.php) and then include just that one file when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `include file.php` to every file where you want to access `foo()`.

To prevent multiple inclusions of same file from different places use `include_once` statement. Then `file.php` will be included only once.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: "to every file" --- it's not correct

Comment: "to every file where you want to access" --- not correct as well. Suppose you have `A.php` and `B.php`. `A.php` includes `file.php`, `B.php` includes `A.php`. In that way `B.php` includes the `file.php` indirectly and doesn't need to have its own include

Comment: Ok, but this depends on structure of included files and if you have to be sure about availability, then you have to include the file. Personaly I'd put `include file.php` in some bootstrap/file which is included with every request.

Comment: " Personaly I'd put include file.php in some bootstrap/file which is included" --- right. That way "to every file where you want to access" isn't correct either. You include it in a bootstrap, not in every file.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this because you need call file with include or get_contents and after eval.

Maybe if you need similar thing you can use namespace.

**Reference**

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.definition.php

Comment: "get_contents and after eval" --- that's **stupid**, seriously

Comment: @zerkms It depends on if you create some framework and you want import one file 2 or more times. you can't put include you need use get_contents and eval.

Comment: if you need that - it's a sign your "framework" architecture is broken from the beginning

Comment: Yes, i know.. I don't use this but we don't dispense any idea or solution to resolve something.

Comment: some ideas (like reading a file + eval'ing it) just don't have any good justification. If one needs that - there is an issue with the code.

Comment: @zerkms it's excatly what i was looking for sth to use as a trick for encoding my codes using the offset part of get_contents and eval it, so not only stupid but also brilliant

Answer (score 0):

Without an extensive knowledge of the language PHP is written in.. Which is C, you cannot do this.

If you have the working knowledge, get the source code for PHP and compile your own methods/functions... Otherwise you will have to include your files.